Flutter InkResponse splash migrates to the center when containedInkWell is set true
Here is a simple flutter code:
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: SizedBox(
          width: 600,
          height: 400,
          child: Material(
            color: Colors.amber,
            child: InkResponse(
              containedInkWell: true,
              splashColor: Colors.blue.shade500,
              radius: 40,
              onTap: () {},
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );

The output is 
As per the containedInkWell docs

This flag also controls whether the splash migrates to the center of the InkResponse or not. If containedInkWell is true, the splash remains centered around the tap location. If it is false, the splash migrates to the center of the InkResponse as it grows.

So, the blue splash must grow and not migrate to the center as the the above code. However, the splash always migrates to the center whether containedInkWell is set true or false

I explored this widget's functionality and experimented with its properties. I believe I have found a solution that aligns with what you're looking for. I hope this meets your requirements
 class NoRadiusInkSplashFactory extends InteractiveInkFeatureFactory {
  @override
  InteractiveInkFeature create({
    required MaterialInkController controller,
    required RenderBox referenceBox,
    required Offset position,
    required Color color,
    required TextDirection textDirection,
    bool containedInkWell = false,
    RectCallback? rectCallback,
    BorderRadius? borderRadius,
    ShapeBorder? customBorder,
    double? radius,
    VoidCallback? onRemoved,
  }) {
   return InkSplash(
  controller: controller,
  referenceBox: referenceBox,
  position: position,
  color: color,
  containedInkWell: true, // chnage this to false
  rectCallback: rectCallback,
  borderRadius: borderRadius,
  customBorder: customBorder,
  radius: 40,
  onRemoved: onRemoved,
  textDirection: textDirection,
);
  }
}

class SplashScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const SplashScreen({super.key});

  @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: SizedBox(
        width: 600,
      height: 400,
      child: Material(
        color: Colors.amber,
        child: InkWell(
          splashFactory: NoRadiusInkSplashFactory(),
          splashColor: Colors.blue.shade500,
          onTap: () {},
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
}
}


It works with InteractiveInkFeatureFactory. but then what's point of offering InkResponse.containedInkWell api? Doesn't the use of splashFactory to achieve this behavior make InkResponse.containedInkWell useless?
